# Download Fonts for Windows

Tags: windows-vista, fonts

In the past, I deleted several fonts on Windows Vista.

And as luck would have it, it has come to pass that Expression Studio 3 won't install because it can't find the needed fonts. I'm installing as admin, no difference there.

So is there anywhere I can find all the fonts, download and unzip them to the fonts directory so that all will be fixed?

BTW: i found the `sfc /scannow` commandline solution, it said that there was an error it cannot fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know which fonts it's looking for?

You can get the new fonts that came with Vista (Constantia, Corbel, Calibri, Cambria, Candara, Consolas) by installing [PowerPoint Viewer 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=048DC840-14E1-467D-8DCA-19D2A8FD7485&displaylang=en) or the [Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint 2007 File Formats](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=941B3470-3AE9-4AEE-8F43-C6BB74CD1466&displaylang=en).

http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Downloading_and_Using_Vista_Web_Fonts